# What is the equivalent of Matlab's mesh function in Julia Plots.jl

Tags: plot, 3d, julia, mesh, plots.jl

In Matlab, we would first use `[x, y] = meshgrid` to generate the grid, then use `mesh(x, y, z)` to plot the 3D plot. I want to use the same funtionality in Julia Plots.jl, which API should I use? And how can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

use `surface`

```
using Plots
xs = range(-2, stop=2, length=100)\
ys = range(-pi, stop=pi, length=100)
f(x,y) = x*sin(y)
surface(xs, ys, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern Julia, v1.17, the approach is to create `x` and `y` ranges. Julia has changed over the years, and used to have `linspace` - it doesn't anymore.

There are three ways to create a range:

```
 x = start:step:end
 x = range(start,end,step=step)
 x = range(start,end,length=npts)
```

You will also need `Plots`. If you precompile it, it takes less time to load.

```
 ]
 pkg > add Plots
 pkg > precompile
 pkg > Ctrl-C
```

You need to select your backend for Plots. Choices are:

1. pyplot() to select PyPlot (also requires Python's MatPlotLib)
2. plotly() to select Plotly (displays in web browser)
3. gr() to select GR, the default

Finally, you need to use `surface` to draw the surface. The function `surface` can take either a function or a matrix of `z` values. The function takes two parameters, `x` and `y`. Either the function is supplied directly, or it is applied to the ranges:

```
z = f.(x',y);
```

One of the ranges is transposed with `'`, and output suppressed with `;`

Surface also takes optional parameters:

- fill = :fillname
- legend = true | false
- size = (width,height)
- clims = (lowlimit,highlimit)

An example:

```
using Plots
plotly()

x=range(-5,5,length=101)
y=range(-5,5,length=101)

function f(x,y)
      r = sqrt(x^2+y^2)
      sinc(r)
end

z = f.(x',y);

surface(x,y,z,size=(1600,1000),fill=:greens,legend=false)
```

[image]