# What are Mesh and Surf equivalents of MATLAB in Julia?

Tags: matlab, plot, julia

MATLAB has two distinct `mesh` and `surf` functions. I found the `surface` [function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70713158/3128341) in Julia, which is similar to the `surf` in MATLAB.

Is there an equivalent of `mesh` in Julia?

The difference is that, `surf` creates kind of a solid surface, whereas `mesh` creates a surface formed by a "mesh" of "wires".

Comment: `wireframe` may be the `mesh` equivalent in some graphics packages (e.g. Makie)

Comment: Actually, Plots.jl has a `Mesh3d` function, but it appears to be poorly documented. An example for Makie can be found in the docs [here](https://docs.makie.org/stable/examples/plotting_functions/wireframe/index.html#wireframe).

Comment: My favorite Julia package dealing with 3D meshes is **Meshes.jl**.

Answer (score 1):

PyPlot.jl and PythonPlot.jl (which wrap Matplotlib) export `mesh` and `surf` functions (corresponding to Matplotlib's `plot_wireframe` and `plot_surface` functions, respectively).

Comment: I am using `wireframe` in PyPlot (`using Plots; pyplot()`). I cannot edit your answer because "there are too many pending edits". Can you edit and add that? Then I will accept your answer.